# adding ram to ubuntu server 18.04 64 bit

Tags: ubuntu, memory, ubuntu-18.04

My server's motherboard supports 32GB of ram. It now has 8GB, two 4GB sticks, the other two slots are empty. But when I add two more sticks of 4GB each the server fails to start with a host of cryptic error messages.

dmidecode -t 16 reports

```
# dmidecode 3.1
Getting SMBIOS data from sysfs.
SMBIOS 2.6 present.

Handle 0x0026, DMI type 16, 15 bytes
Physical Memory Array
        Location: System Board Or Motherboard
        Use: System Memory
        Error Correction Type: None
        Maximum Capacity: 8 GB
        Error Information Handle: Not Provided
        Number Of Devices: 4
```

perl memconf-v3.12.pl reports

```
ECS GeForce 8000 series (AMD Athlon(TM) II X2 240 2800MHz)
Memory Error Correction: None
Maximum Memory: 8192MB (8GB)
DIMM0 BANK0: 4096MB 400 MT/s Synchronous DDR2 DIMM, Kllisre DDR2 4G  0
DIMM1 BANK1: 4096MB 400 MT/s Synchronous DDR2 DIMM, Kllisre DDR2 4G  0
empty memory sockets: DIMM2 BANK2, DIMM3 BANK3
total memory = 8192MB (8GB)
```

The information I've found on the web is confusing, some claiming 18.04 can only support 8GB of ram and both dmidecode and memconf seem to confirm that. I'm hoping someone can clarify this for me. I'm perfectly willing to reinstall the system to have it recognize the additional ram but I don't want to go on a fool's errand if 8GB is its limit.

Comment: Memory should add just fine without any issue, provided the memory and mainboard are error-free. 99% of the time, errors in the adding process mean there is a problem with the memory sticks, the slots in the mainboard, the mainboard controllers, or something else.

Comment: I run **16.04** with 32GB, so I would expect 18.04 to do at least as well.